# In Python how to map different debug level messages to different files

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7

I need to map the different logging level messages to different files, it is like mapping all info log messages to info.log and all debug messages to debug.log, is that possible in python if yes, how can it be done.

Thanks in Adavance

Comment: can you give the link for duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

you can probably achieve this by creating a log handler for each file, then attaching a [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects) to each handler

Comment: I am new to Python, can I have an example

Comment: your question has been marked as a duplicate - please follow the link to the original question to see some code